# Improving table view frame rate when downloading images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, sdwebimage

I am trying to improve the performance of my table view which contains cells that load images from the web. I have so far changed the library that I'm using to one that caches the images, and this helps quite a bit, however it isn't quite perfect yet.

I was reading about moving the process onto a different thread, so I've been trying to implement this to improve performance further, however I haven't figured out how to write it in code.

At the moment (before the change), I have this:

```
    cell.rideImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: ride.rideImageSmall!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Unloaded"))
```

I tried changing it to something like this:

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().imageDownloader.downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: self.ride.rideImageSmall!), options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.HighPriority, progress: nil, completed: nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //
        }
    }
```

but that's as far as I got, and I'm not sure it's right. If that is the correct way to do it, how do I actually set the image that's been downloaded? And if it's not, can someone show a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: SDWebImage automatically use async image downloading (using background thread) to get image and then in main thread set image to UIImageView. For this you don't need to manipulate with threads. What is your problem with performance when using solution before change? What was slow in your app?

Comment: Ah, I see. It works better than before, but there is still some frame rate drop which is especially noticeable when scrolling of the table view slows down.

Comment: Do you reuse cells with one of the deque-methods?

Comment: Yeah, I am. It looks like I've discovered the issue though. I am using shadows on each cell, and after removing them, it scrolls perfectly.

Comment: If you really need shadows for design reasons you could pre-render them and add as normal images.